# Wrap Group of Classes With HTML

Tags: jquery, expressionengine

I have an unordered list that has about 25 list items that have different classes after each 5 list items. Example below.

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo1">Hello</li>
    <li class="foo1">Hello</li>
    <li class="foo1">Hello</li>
    <li class="foo1">Hello</li>
    <li class="foo1">Hello</li>
    <li class="foo2">Hello</li>
    <li class="foo2">Hello</li>
    <li class="foo2">Hello</li>
    <li class="foo2">Hello</li>
    <li class="foo2">Hello</li>
</ul>
```

I need to wrap each 5 list items within that class in an ul. These list items are outputted by a CMS, so I can't code it myself. I know I can use jquery .wrap() on the class, but that would wrap each list item with that class in an ul. So how can I wrap the 5 list items that have the class with an ul?

The output should be this:

```
<ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="foo1">Hello</li>
        <li class="foo1">Hello</li>
        <li class="foo1">Hello</li>
        <li class="foo1">Hello</li>
        <li class="foo1">Hello</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="foo2">Hello</li>
        <li class="foo2">Hello</li>
        <li class="foo2">Hello</li>
        <li class="foo2">Hello</li>
        <li class="foo2">Hello</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: In addition to the fine answers below you can also do this on the server side using conditionals and {count}.  One day EE will have the modulus operator and it will be much cleaner but until then you can do something like {if count=="5" OR count=="10" OR ... }</ul><ul>{/if}. Also I suspect that if EE knows to switch classes I would venture you could also use the same method to close and open your lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `$('.foo1').wrapAll('<ul/>');`

Added a jsfiddle that finds the classes within the ul and wraps them (in case you don't know the inner class names going in).

```
function classList(elem){
    var classes = [];
    $.each( elem, function(index,item) {
        elemClasses = $(item).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
        $.each(elemClasses, function(index,item) {
           if(classes.indexOf(item) === -1) classes.push(item);
        });
    });
    return classes;
}

$.each(classList($('ul li')), function(index, item) {
    $('.' + item).wrapAll('<ul/>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/C5Dzn/

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop through and [wrap them](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    $('.foo'+i).wrapAll('<ul/>');
}
```

Or if you don't know how many there will be:

```
var i = 1;
while($('.foo'+i).length > 0)
{
    $('.foo'+i).wrapAll('<ul/>');
    i++;
}
```